# A large number of CLOSE_WAIT occurs by using zuul

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

when i use springcloud zuul, there is a large number of TCP CLOSE_WAIT status occurs，can anyone knows why its happens?

here is my zuul configuration

parent pom

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
```

1. pom.xml

   ```
   <dependencies>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
       <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
   </dependency>
          <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
       <version>Edgware.SR2</version>
       <type>pom</type>
       <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   ```
2. application.properties

   ```
   server.port=8081
   spring.application.name=zuul-server-test
   eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
   eureka.instance.instance-id=${spring.cloud.client.ipAddress}:${server.port}
   eureka.instance.leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds=5
   eureka.instance.leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds=10
   eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://127.0.0.1:8080/eureka/

   zuul.add-host-header=true
   zuul.sensitive-headers=

   hystrix.command.default.execution.timeout.enable=true
   hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=60000
   zuul.host.connect-timeout-millis=60000
   zuul.host.socket-timeout-milllis=60000

   ribbon.eureka.enabled=true
   ribbon.ReadTimeout=60000
   ribbon.ConnectTimeout=30000
   ribbon.MaxAutoRetries=0
   ribbon.MaxAutoRetriesNextServer=1
   ribbon.OkToRetryOnAllOperations=false
   ribbon.httpclient.enabled=false
   ribbon.okhttp.enabled=true

   zuul.routes.hello.path=/hello/**
   zuul.routes.hello.sensitiveHeaders=
   zuul.routes.hello.service-id=hello-server
   ```

java

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableDiscoveryClient
    @EnableZuulProxy
    public class DevcloudZuulApplication {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(DevcloudZuulApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

when i visit http://localhost:8081/hello/index.html, tcp links created, port 8082 is the hello-server

```
    tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.120.20:8082 ::ffff:192.168.120.20:21505 ESTABLISHED 47968/java          
    tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.120.20:21505 ::ffff:192.168.120.20:8082 ESTABLISHED 132689/java         
    tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.120.20:8082 ::ffff:192.168.120.20:21510 ESTABLISHED 47968/java  
    tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.120.20:21510 ::ffff:192.168.120.20:8082 ESTABLISHED 132689/java        
    tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.120.20:8082 ::ffff:192.168.120.20:21504 ESTABLISHED 47968/java          
    tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.120.20:21504 ::ffff:192.168.120.20:8082 ESTABLISHED 132689/java
```

then it changes

```
    tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.120.20:8082 ::ffff:192.168.120.20:21505 FIN_WAIT2   -                   
    tcp        1      0 ::ffff:192.168.120.20:21505 ::ffff:192.168.120.20:8082 CLOSE_WAIT  132689/java         
    tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.120.20:8082 ::ffff:192.168.120.20:21510 FIN_WAIT2    -        
    tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.120.20:21510 ::ffff:192.168.120.20:8082 CLOSE_WAIT 132689/java 
    tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.120.20:8082 ::ffff:192.168.120.20:21504 FIN_WAIT2   -                   
    tcp        1      0 ::ffff:192.168.120.20:21504 ::ffff:192.168.120.20:8082 CLOSE_WAIT  132689/java
```

at last,

```
    tcp        1      0 ::ffff:192.168.120.20:21505 ::ffff:192.168.120.20:8082 CLOSE_WAIT  132689/java         
    tcp        1      0 ::ffff:192.168.120.20:21504 ::ffff:192.168.120.20:8082 CLOSE_WAIT  132689/java         
    tcp        1      0 ::ffff:192.168.120.20:21510 ::ffff:192.168.120.20:8082 CLOSE_WAIT  132689/java
```

and this status will continue through hours.

Answer (score 0):

`CLOSE_WAIT` described here: [TCP connection status](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.halu101/constatus.htm)

> This endpoint has received a close request from the remote endpoint and this TCP is now waiting for a connection termination request from the local application.

Ribbon uses a connection pool to send request to upstream. Every time, it releases connection instead of close it to avoid overhead of establishing new connection.

The connections in pool has alive time by configuring `ribbon.PoolKeepAliveTime` which default value is 15 * 60 seconds.

```
public class DefaultClientConfigImpl implements IClientConfig {
    public static final long DEFAULT_POOL_KEEP_ALIVE_TIME = 15 * 60L;
    public static final TimeUnit DEFAULT_POOL_KEEP_ALIVE_TIME_UNITS = TimeUnit.SECONDS;
}


public class OkHttpRibbonConfiguration {
@Value("${ribbon.client.name}")
private String name = "client";

@Configuration
protected static class OkHttpClientConfiguration {
    private OkHttpClient httpClient;

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(ConnectionPool.class)
    public ConnectionPool httpClientConnectionPool(IClientConfig config, OkHttpClientConnectionPoolFactory connectionPoolFactory) {
        Integer maxTotalConnections = config.getPropertyAsInteger(
                CommonClientConfigKey.MaxTotalConnections,
                DefaultClientConfigImpl.DEFAULT_MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS);
        Object timeToLiveObj = config
                .getProperty(CommonClientConfigKey.PoolKeepAliveTime);
        Long timeToLive = DefaultClientConfigImpl.DEFAULT_POOL_KEEP_ALIVE_TIME;
        Object ttlUnitObj = config
                .getProperty(CommonClientConfigKey.PoolKeepAliveTimeUnits);
        TimeUnit ttlUnit = DefaultClientConfigImpl.DEFAULT_POOL_KEEP_ALIVE_TIME_UNITS;
        if (timeToLiveObj instanceof Long) {
            timeToLive = (Long) timeToLiveObj;
        }
        if (ttlUnitObj instanceof TimeUnit) {
            ttlUnit = (TimeUnit) ttlUnitObj;
        }
        return connectionPoolFactory.create(maxTotalConnections, timeToLive, ttlUnit);
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, in my environment, the CLOSE_WAIT state lasts for hours, and it's no use to change the parameter `ribbon.PoolKeepAliveTime`.  when i delete the following config , the problems is gone, but still unkonw why, i will continue focus on it.  ribbon.MaxAutoRetries=0
ribbon.MaxAutoRetriesNextServer=1
ribbon.OkToRetryOnAllOperations=false
ribbon.httpclient.enabled=false
ribbon.okhttp.enabled=true